# tunnel to a webserver with putty and access apache there as if from localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, localhost, putty

I have a webserver with a htaccess rule that permits only contact to a webservice from 127.0.0.1 (I cannot change this). I already configured putty to make a tunnel to that webserver and when I enter localhost:port in my browser I see the page hosted there. But to access the webservice it has to be as if I come from 127.0.0.1. How can I do this?

Comment: If you have an ssh tunnel open, you _come_ from 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I set up a tunnel and connected to my webserver using it. I noticed that the connections were logged as coming from `::1` which is the IPv6 'localhost'. If you allow from 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost then these will be blocked.

You should be able to solve this by changing the tunnel definition in putty. Instead of using `localhost:80` as the destination use `127.0.0.1:80`.